# python observer pattern

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python but I've run into a hitch when trying to implement a variation of the observer pattern.

```
class X(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(Voter)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    # Register 
    Y.register(X)
```

This doesn't seem to work because it says X is not defined.  A couple of things are possible:

A) There is a way to refer to the current class (not the instance, but the class object).

B) You can't even run code outside a method.  (I thought this may work almost like a static constructor - it would just get run once).

Comment: Are you really intending to pass in the class here? Instances I would understand, but the class? Unless register registers factories, but then you have a component registry, and that's not exactly observer pattern. In an observer pattern Y would notify X of things, which you can't do when X is a class.

Comment: What's Y?  Another class?  Not an object?  Why aren't you using object instances for this?  Why are you trying to use classes for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with running (limited) code in the class definition:

```
class X(object):
  print("Loading X")
```

However, you can not refer to X because it is not yet fully defined.

Answer (score 5):

In python, code defined in a class block is executed and only **then**, depending on various things---like what has been defined in this block---a class is created. So if you want to relate one class with another, you'd write:

```
class X(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(Voter)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=200)

# Register 
Y.register(X)
```

And this behaviour is not related to django.